# HTML+CSS: 'a' width doesn't work

Tags: html, css, doctype

I have the following code:

CSS part:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .menu
    {
        width:200px;
    }

    .menu ul
    {
        list-style-image:none;
        list-style-type:none;
    }

    .menu li
    {
        margin:2px;
    }

    .menu A
    {
        height:25px;
        width:170px;
        background:url(./images/button-51.png);
        padding:2px 5px ;
    }

    .menu A:link
    {
        height:25px;
        width:170px;
        background:url(./images/button-51.png);
        padding:2px 5px ;
    }
</style>
```

HTML part:

Everything work fine, but when I add 'DOCTYPE' element in the beginning of the HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

the width of 'a' element is not taken into account.

**Question 1:** Why?

**Question 2:** How to fix that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 128, accepted):

> Question 1: Why?

Because it's by default not a [block element](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html).

> Question 2: How to fix that?

Make it a block element using `display: block;`, or an inline block by `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: wow man, you just saved me a ton of headache! I couldn't figure out WHY my anchor tags' width couldn't be adjusted!

Answer (score 10):

make block for anchor  tag add `display:block` in style

```
.menu a
{
    display:block;
    height:25px;
    width:170px;
    background:url(./images/button-51.png);
    padding:2px 5px ;
}
```

**NOTE:** dont repet all elements in `.menu a:link` class.. just add changes or new styles.
**NOTE:** always use lowercase in html and css code

Answer (score 3):

add display block in a :

```
.menu A
    {
        display: block;
        height:25px;
        width:170px;
        background:url(./images/button-51.png);
        padding:2px 5px ;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me, but since I wanted all of my links to be on the same line I used `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 2):

A link is an inline element by default; add `display: block;` and it'll use the set width.

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu A
    {
        float: left;
        height:25px;
        width:170px;
        background:url(./images/button-51.png);
        padding:2px 5px ;
    }
```