# Issue with linking a box

Tags: html, css

I would like to hover a link (`<a>` tag which contains a `<div>` tag), so the color becomes red BUT only when I hover the yellow field! My problem is that you can also hover it if the cursor is not on the yellow field.

I know that I could put the a tag into the div tag but I want to link the whole box and not only the text.

I also tried to use `a { width: 100px; }` but that is of course not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/3phy4950/

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Comment: The balise a is not a block element https://jsfiddle.net/3phy4950/2/
put display:block [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706921/htmlcss-a-width-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work with width, because you are applying this style to the a tag. But a tags are display inline by default which means they dont take the whole space / line.

The div tag is display block by default, which means it will take the whole space / line.

What you need is to change the display style from the `a div` to inline:

```
a div {
   display: inline;
}
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3phy4950/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `inline-block` as the display format for the `<a>` tag.

```
a {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96jhk316/)

Answer (score -1):

What about this:

```
<div class="btn" onclick="location.href='http://google.com'">» Hover Me</div>
```

And the css:

```
.btn {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100px;
}

.btn:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: The semantics of this seem a bit wonky, not to mention the implications for browser history capture and graceful degradation in the absence of JavaScript. If the OP wants a link, they should use an anchor tag IMO.